# Flume: Possibility of persisting the Source & Sink connections

Tags: flume, flume-ng

Though it’s against the basic design principle of Flume, I have one question.
Is this possible to persist the connection between source & sink and re-use ?

We are using HTTP source, File channel & Kafka sink and with that configuration, not getting the expected throughput because of the re-connections of the source & sink for every event.

So, would it be possible to re-use the same HTTP and Kafka connections for multiple transactions ? (even with a custom source & sink)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding your question... There is no direct communication between the source and the sink, but they are connected through the channel. The source puts Flume events into the channel, and the sink gets those events; such puts and gets are disk writes and reads in your case, since you are using a file channel; if you were using a memory channel, the writes and reads would be related to volatile memory.

Maybe you are wondering if you can ignore the channel and directly pass the Flume events the source builds to the sink... In that case Flume has no sense, since such an architecture ignores all the benefits of using an internal channel (reliability, fault tolerance, peaks of loads absorption...), and a simple script or application in charge of receiving the data and directly writing to Kafka may fit your needs (of course, such a solution will not scale, will not be fault tolerant, you will have to deal with http-like reception of data and Kafka API for outputting the data, and many more things you miss if Flume is not used).

Finally, you may be asking for persistent connection between the external data source sending the data and the Flume http source receiving it... That's interesting, and I think you could achieve such persistent connection by sending a large value regarding the `keep-alive` http header.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated explanation. Sorry that I could not properly convey my thoughts. Your last paragraph correctly conveys my need. I want to persist the connection between HTTP client and HTTP source, for which you said is doable by keep-alive. Second, I want to persist the connection between Kafka sink and the Kafka cluster too.